# Simple question about this chain of sheaf morphisms

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

From 'Introduction to Algebraic Geometry' by Justin R. Smith:

[image]

What is the role of that intermediate sheaf $\mathcal{A}_{\mathbb{C}}$ in the chain in this example ?

Could we not have got from the constant sheaf $\underline{ 2 \pi i \mathbb{Z} }$ straight to $\mathcal{N}_{\mathbb{C^*}}$ via some sheaf morphism ?

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of exact sequences for modules? It's the same idea here.

Comment: I have now read a little about them in the same text (p 452), still, i am not sure I understand everything. What is the sheaf morphism between $\underline{ 2 \pi i \mathbb{Z} }$ and  $\mathcal{A}_{\mathbb{C}}$ ?

Comment: The sheaf morphism there is inclusion. Locally constant functions are analytic.